# Active Git branch is "(no branch)" on hudson CI

Tags: git, hudson, git-checkout

My Ant build.xml script starts with

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo>GIT_BRANCH = ${env.GIT_BRANCH}</echo>
<echo>PWD = ${env.PWD}</echo>
```

Hudson CI is setup to build when any branch changes. Console output is...

```
Commencing build of Revision 90906a63929e9074035eb5b10c71ee055ad3e13c (origin/DPM-48)
GitAPI created
Checking out Revision 90906a63929e9074035eb5b10c71ee055ad3e13c (origin/DPM-48)
[workspace] $ git.exe checkout -f 90906a63929e9074035eb5b10c71ee055ad3e13c
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\Program Files\WinAnt\bin\ant.bat" -file build.xml ...'
 [echo] GIT_BRANCH = ${env.GIT_BRANCH}
 [echo] PWD = /cygdrive/d/.hudson
```

From the console output, Hudson knows it is building topic branch DPM-48 but environment variable GIT_BRANCH is not set and 'git branch' returns that git is at a 'detached HEAD' state

```
* (no branch)
master
DPM-48
```

What I want to know is which branch I'm building on hudson.  There must be a way to do this.

Comment: http://github.com/hudson/Hudson-GIT-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java I found out that the Git SCM plugin for Hudson overrides a buildEnvVars() method to set the GIT_BRANCH environment variable but it is not coming through to the ant script using <property environment="env"/> <echo>GIT_BRANCH = ${env.GIT_BRANCH}</echo>

Comment: good point, I have integrated it in my answer, plus a reference to an issue which might explain your current situation.

Comment: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6856 seems to imply the detached branch issue on hudson might be fixed.  i'm going to make sure i have the latest versions of hudson and the git plugin.

Comment: good point, I have included that issue reference in my answer. I will also include the result of your test (with Hudson 1.379 I suppose)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

RESOLVED

After seeing the comment by abayer in [Hudson bug 6856](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6856), I took the following steps:

- Using the Hudson Plugin Manager, I updated my Hudson Git Plugin version 1.1) to get abayer's fix.
- Using the Hudson Job Configuration, I clicked the "Advanced" button under "Source Code Management" -> "Branches to Build". I then changed the "Local branch to use" to something to use for a name.  It doesn't matter what.
- Then I clicked the "Save" button and started a build with "Build Now"

[image]

The build log shows

```
[workspace] $ git.exe checkout -b ChangeTester d6caef27759495c5714923c1ddf19551a70d6083
```

Instead of

```
[workspace] $ git.exe checkout -f d6caef27759495c5714923c1ddf19551a70d6083
```

Which means that I am not in a 'detached head' state and can therefore do commits, create tags, and push.

I can use 'git rev-parse HEAD' to get the commit hash and find that in the output of 'git show-ref' to find the real name of the branch if I need it.

I'm now able to push successful build tags to my git repo.

Comment: I wasted a couple of hours trying to figure this one out... Thank you!

Comment: This lines up with this answer too http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/git-plugin-after-checkout-not-on-any-branch-tp4673842p4673855.html

Answer (score 10):

Note: the [OP milkplus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245777/milkplus)'s comment refers to recent [**Hudson bug 6856**](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6856) (June 2010), which mentions:

> **Git builds with detached head no matter what**

While it is unclear if that particular issue will be solved (answers suggest it might actually "work as designed"!), it also refers to [this version of hudson Git Plugin](http://github.com/abayer/Hudson-GIT-plugin/tree/HUDSON-6856), allowing to checkout a local branch.

---

You are in a **[`DETACHED HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999907/git-push-says-everything-up-to-date-even-though-i-have-local-changes/1000009#1000009)** because, as the git plugin is working right now, it did checkout directly a commit SHA1, and not a branch `HEAD`.

> The state you are in while your `HEAD` is detached is not recorded by any branch (which is natural --- you are not on any branch).
>   What this means is that you can discard your temporary commits and merges by switching back to an existing branch.

Your building script could first try to [find what branch the relevant commit is coming from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706797/git-finding-what-branch-a-commit-came-from).

---

As the OP [milkplus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245777/milkplus) realized by looking at the [source code of the Hudson Git Plugin](http://github.com/hudson/Hudson-GIT-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java):

```
public void buildEnvVars(AbstractBuild build, java.util.Map<String, String> env) {
    super.buildEnvVars(build, env);
    String branch = getSingleBranch(build);
    if(branch != null){
        env.put(GIT_BRANCH, branch);
    }
}
```

An environment variable `GIT_BRANCH` is set, but it doesn't appear to have any value in the xml build script:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo>GIT_BRANCH = ${env.GIT_BRANCH}</echo>
```

If that is the case, it may be because of [issue 7554](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7554):

> `GIT_BRANCH` not set when multiple branches are selected for build
>
> > > When trying to identify what branch the current build are on, I found that the `GIT_BRANCH` environment variable is not set when more then a single branch is selected to be built.
> >
> > This isn't really a bug so much as a feature request, I think - the `GIT_BRANCH` env var is only set if there's a single branch, so as such, it's not relevant if/when there are multiple branches. I'm not sure how we'd format an env var for multiple branches in this context.
>
> I thought that `GIT_BRANCH` shall be set to the branch that is currently building.
>   Like if the build is on master it will contain the master.
>
> That would help to for example push to another remote that branch that was built during this build.
>   Or Triggering another Build with the correct branch set to be built.

Kind of mirror the [NPE described here](http://evgenyg.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/hudson-git-maven/)

[image]

> For some reason Git plugin started to pass null value for `GIT_BRANCH` environment variable.
>   This caused Maven plugin to fail in `System.getProperties().putAll(systemProps)` call.
>
> The solution was to use "`master`" as default Git branch instead of "`**`" or empty String.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how to find the branch name that triggered Hudson to build.

Comment: @milkplus: but the link I mention should contain various script (including the `what-branch` script in my answer there) made precisely to find out the branch name.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you, very much for sharing this solution!

I had some trouble to find this optional dialog to set the local branch - and to show others that this is also still the current approach also in year 2015 I would to attach some screenshot of the current gui dialogs of jenkins.

[image][image]