# Saving Git SHA1 when building with Hudson similar to the CVS_BRANCH tag for CVS

Tags: java, git, ant, hudson

We have migrated from CVS to Git.  Our Hudson build script used to save the value of the CVS_BRANCH environment variable in the generated build along with the Hudson BUILD_ID to allow for later investigation.

I cannot figure out how Hudson (or the Git plugin) presents the Git SHA1 name of the current commit to the ant script, as I cannot locate any definite source saying where I should look.

I'd prefer not to invoke git to get it if it is present in the environment, but can do if that is necessary.

What have I missed?

Comment: Isn't this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858563/active-git-branch-is-no-branch-on-hudson-ci?

Comment: @VonC, yes closely, but I can probably live with the SHA1 code - I want to be able to go back at the exact commit from which the build was made.

Comment: ørn SHA1 is good (but not very satisfactory), [`git describe`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-to-get-the-git-commit-count/677888) is better (but means invoking git, which is what you don't want). The concept of (named) branch is a "transient" one, as branches can be deleted/renamed at will.

Comment: "don't want" is too strong, "prefer not" is better.  I'd like Hudson to tell what it knows instead of having to use heuristics to derive something that may or may not be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that [jGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit) supports the "rev-parse HEAD" command, which in combination with the `<java jar="jgit...jar" fork="true" args="rev-parse HEAD" outputproperty="git.SHA1" />` did exactly what I wanted, namely got the SHA1 into an ant property so I could use it later.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you really want to avoid calling git command (`git describe` or `git rev-parse`), then you can do the following:

1. Look up $GIT_DIR/HEAD file.  If it is symbolic link, its target is fully qualified name of current branch (e.g. 'refs/heads/master' if current branch is 'master'); shouldn't happen except in very old repositories managed by very old git.

   If it is ordinary file, it is either of the form `ref: refs/heads/<branch>` (so called symref), or it contains SHA-1 id of current commit (so called "detached HEAD" aka. anonymous branch: '(no branch)' in `git branch` output.
2. Current commit is either in $GIT_DIR/refs/head/*branch* file, or it can be found in the $GIT_DIR/packed-refs file.  If both exist, then loose ref (in a seperate file named after fully qualified branch name) wins.

But I am not sure if it is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The [git plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin) exposes a GIT_COMMIT environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get buildnumber from git using Ant and JGit you can use [jgit-buildnumber-ant-task](https://github.com/alx3apps/jgit-buildnumber). It can give you tag name, branch name, commit sha1, and commit's count in current branch as Ant variables.