# Setup remote tracking in Jenkins / Git

Tags: git, jenkins, sbt, jenkins-plugins

With Jenkins, I'm checking out a project that later it builds using SBT. But when it tries to execute the [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) plugin, it complains:

```
No tracking branch is set up. Either configure a remote tracking branch, or remove the pushChanges release part
```

This is my Jenkins GIT plugin configuration:

- **Repository URL:** points to .git file
- **Name:** blank
- **Refspec:** blank
- **Branches to build/Branch Specifier (blank for default):** develop (the branch I'm building)
- **Checkout/merge to local branch (optional):** develop

I set those items following the guide that answers [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511390/jenkins-git-plugin-detached-head).

I think the SBT-release plugin needs the remote tracking in order make a tag on the branch.

Comment: Try using `origin/develop` instead of `develop`. I don't think this is your problem, but I've been configuring Jenkins all week and this was important in our setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve it I have no choice but to build a command line script:

```
git checkout develop || git checkout -b develop
git reset --hard origin/develop
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/develop develop
git pull
```

and execute it before the SBT build.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you want to build from master.

In Jenkins in GIT section select:

```
Branches to build:     master
```

also add:

```
Additional Behaviours: 
      Check out to specific local branch:      master
```

Build step

Execute Shell:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

And then add your SBT build step

```
sbt "release with-defaults"
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.git/config` file needs the following three lines in it:

```
[branch "master"]
  remote = origin
  merge = refs/heads/master
```

both the other answers add those, but you can just add them manually

Answer (score 0):

In my case, remote was missing. In order to solve this problem I've used the following command lines before calling Build using sbt.

```
git remote add origin git@foo/bar.git || git remote -v
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```