# RefNotFoundException with gradle-git

Tags: git, gradle, jgit

While using the nice [gradle-git plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) (version 0.6.5) I encountered an issue when checking out a branch.

```
task checkoutMaster(type:GitCheckout){
    setBranchName "master"
}
```

The task above caused a `org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException` probably because I was not on any branch at that time.

I was told that the `Ref master can not be resolved` which seemed odd to me, considering that I could do a `git checkout master` and be just fine.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing this line in my task:

```
setCreateBranch true
```

This doesn't overwrite the existing `master` branch (which I dreaded a bit as someone who has yet to reach Git-Zen).

---

Edit:

The reason for being on no branch was because Jenkins' Git plugin checks out a single commit instead of a branch per default. That's why I ended up with a detached head.

Here's how to change the plugin's behavior: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511390/jenkins-git-plugin-detached-head#answer-23131277)