# Detached HEAD w/Jenkins Git Plugin and Branch Specifier

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins v2.19

Git Plugin v2.5.3

Under Branches to Build I am specifying 2 branches:

```
*/develop
```

and

```
*/master
```

This results in a `HEAD detached at {git commit hash}`.  I have different actions in my gradle build scripts that use the current git branch as a trigger to take different actions.

How can I make this checkout develop to develop and master to master rather than a detached HEAD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Git plugin detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511390/jenkins-git-plugin-detached-head)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set the following:

```
Additional Behaviours > Check out to specific local branch
```

Click on "?" to see details about this option.

Comment: This worked by leaving the `Check out to a specific local branch` field blank.  Figured it out, but glad I get to give someone the checkmark.