# How do I achieve git Additional Behaviors => Checkout to specific local branch in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

How do we achieve Git Additional Behavior in Jenkins pipeline?

> Additional Behaviors
> => checkout to specific local branch

Answer (score 5):

check this one http://your-Jenkins:8080/pipeline-syntax/ , you can have samples of all your installed plugins.

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'your-sub-directory']], gitTool: 'Default', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'd767bb7a-4c1e-4654-a310-996d4ece5b02', url: 'git@github.com:yyy/xxx.git']]])
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you any help

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. btw do we have any helm ( https://github.com/kubernetes/helm )plugin for jenkins pipeline ?

Comment: I am not familiar with any helm plugin

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was for "Check out to specific local branch" but the answer was for "Check out to a sub-directory" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the pipeline syntax in your Jenkins job slide bar **Pipeline Syntax** section.

[image]

1、**Sample Step** select **checkout: Check out from version control**

2、click **Additional Behaviours** Add button

3、select  **checkout to specific local branch**

4、click bottom **Generate Pipeline Script** button，you will get pipeline script.