# how to get current branch name through plugin

Tags: java, git, groovy

I need current branch name of the project where I'm deploying a plugin,
So code for current branch name in the plugin's groovy class goes like this,

```
   def getCurrentGitBranch() {
        def gitBranch = "Unknown branch"
        try {
            def workingDir = new File(ProjectConfig.projectDir)
            def result = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute(null, workingDir)
            result.waitFor()
            if (result.exitValue() == 0) {
                gitBranch = result.text.trim()
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Problem occurred while fetching current branch name from git.")
        }
        log.info("Branch Name [ "+ gitBranch + "]")
        return gitBranch
    }
```

But for some reason when while deploying the project on cloud using jenkins this function return HEAD instead of current branch of the project for which I'm trying to deploy.

I tried a lot with different scenarios but no luck, how do I make sure the plugin I'm using fetches the current branch of the project for which deployment is being done.

Answer (score 3):

For any reasons, you are in detached HEAD. *(Please read [this article](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit) if you don't know what is a detached HEAD.)* 
Usually, you are in this state if you do something like `git checkout SHA-1`; `git checkout tag` (these are examples between severals).

It seems Jenkins checkout the code in detached head. You can go to `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/YOUR_PROJECT` to check this with `git status`.

**To correct your issue,** you have to add `Additional Behaviours > Check out to a specific local branch` under *SCM management* section of Jenkins project configuration.
Reading following link may helps you : [Jenkins Git plugin detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15829994/2394026)

Comment: Thanks Flows for your explanation I check on jenkins config its deploying master branch with build parameter as a version, how do I make sure on Jenkins that is in detached HEAD any idea

Comment: I give some more details in my answer

Comment: Actually I can see in the logs of Jenkins for deployment  git checkout -f 63812e412cffb50d6b0debbf7baf5be359ae39d2 this means its on detached HEAD right? from whatever I have read about detached HEAD

Comment: Yes it is right. To change this, you have to add "Additional Behaviours" / "Check out to a specific local branch" in SCM management under Jenkins project configuration