# lerna publish on Jenkins "git remote update" Fails "Could not read from remote repository."

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, github, lerna

I am trying to set up `lerna` with `jenkins` to publish after all my tests pass. I have the command running but it's failing.

I can't find any documentation on how to get this to work. I need this command to have access to push the lerna tags, as well as the updated version numbers to the master branch, and I also need Jenkins to not fall into an infinite loop.

My first issue was this:

```
> lerna publish --yes --cd-version=patch

lerna info version 3.0.0-beta.17
lerna info versioning independent
lerna ERR! ENOGIT Detached git HEAD, please checkout a branch to publish changes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abide@1.0.0 publish: `lerna publish --yes --cd-version=patch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the abide@1.0.0 publish script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T03_18_59_152Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abide@1.0.0 jenkins: `npm run versions && npm run test && npm run publish`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the abide@1.0.0 jenkins script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T03_18_59_167Z-debug.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Which I fixed by doing this:
[Jenkins Git plugin detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511390/jenkins-git-plugin-detached-head/23131277#23131277)

Here's what I set everything to:

[image]

Now I am having this issue:

```
> lerna publish --yes --cd-version=patch

lerna info version 3.0.0-beta.17
lerna info versioning independent
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: git remote update
lerna ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
lerna ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
lerna ERR! and the repository exists.
lerna ERR! error: Could not fetch origin
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR! Fetching origin
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR!     at makeError (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/child-process/node_modules/execa/index.js:169:9)
lerna ERR!     at Function.module.exports.sync (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/child-process/node_modules/execa/index.js:338:15)
lerna ERR!     at Object.execSync (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/child-process/index.js:21:16)
lerna ERR!     at Object.isBehindUpstream (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/git-utils/index.js:206:25)
lerna ERR!     at PublishCommand.initialize (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/publish/index.js:92:24)
lerna ERR!     at Promise.resolve.then (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/command/index.js:228:24)
lerna ERR! lerna Command failed: git remote update
lerna ERR! lerna Permission denied (publickey).
lerna ERR! lerna fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
lerna ERR! lerna 
lerna ERR! lerna Please make sure you have the correct access rights
lerna ERR! lerna and the repository exists.
lerna ERR! lerna error: Could not fetch origin
lerna ERR! lerna 
lerna ERR! lerna Fetching origin
lerna ERR! lerna 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abide@1.0.0 publish: `lerna publish --yes --cd-version=patch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the abide@1.0.0 publish script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T03_29_06_133Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! abide@1.0.0 jenkins: `npm run versions && npm run test && npm run publish`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the abide@1.0.0 jenkins script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T03_29_06_144Z-debug.log
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I get `lerna publish` to work in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ssh'd into the jenkins box and `cd` into the workspace.

I ran `git remote update` and it stdout this:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.

It seems I didn't have github's IP added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure with which account Jenkins is running on the Jenkins box:

If you do have the right `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` private/public key, Jenkins must run with that user for ~ to reflect the right HOME.

If you can connect to the Jenkins machine, you can then test your ssh connection with:

```
cd /apth/to/repo
git remote -v
  # should return an ssh URL
  # like:
  # git@aserver.com
ssh -T git@aserver.com
```

The [OP ThomasReggi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340688/thomasreggi) confirms the account issue [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993136/lerna-publish-on-jenkins-git-remote-update-fails-could-not-read-from-remote-r/49993562#comment87004148_49993562) with:

> I have been SSH'd into the machine via root and can view access.
>   I am pulling the repo down with a user and have a key in Jenkins using the Git plugin, but now lerna is running outside that plugin and needs ssh access to the repo and it's not available at the user level.
>
> All I needed to do was add the SSH Agent plugin and in my job's configure use the same SSH credentials I used to setup the GitHub plugin.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I checked a) I have a `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` b) I can `git remote -v` c) I can connect via ssh any other reason why this might be happening?

Comment: @ThomasReggi Did you try again your Jenkins job, is it still failing now that ~/.ssh/know_hosts was updated? And more importantly, are you sure Jenkins is using the right account?

Comment: @ThomasReggi Do you have the SSH Credential Plugin installed?

Comment: I believe I understand what is going wrong. I have been SSH'd into the machine via root and can view access. I am pulling the repo down with a user and have a key in jenkins using the git plugin but now lerna is running outside that plugin and needs ssh access to the repo and it's not available at the user level. Make sense?

Comment: @ThomasReggi yes: using the wrong account: this is what my answer was stating all along.

Comment: All I needed to do was add the SSH Agent plugin and in my job's configure use the same SSH credentials I used to setup the github plugin. Thanks for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: Ok, I will edit the answer. I am commuting at the moment

Comment: @ThomasReggi I have edited the answer and included your comment for more visibility.