# lerna fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/heads/origin/master...heads/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: node.js, git, jenkins, ssh, lerna

This is apart of my series of questions pertaining to how to get lerna running in Jenkins.

Previous issues:

[lerna publish on Jenkins "git remote update" Fails "Could not read from remote repository."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993136/lerna-publish-on-jenkins-git-remote-update-fails-could-not-read-from-remote-r)

```
> lerna publish --yes --cd-version=patch

lerna info version 3.0.0-beta.17
lerna info versioning independent
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed: git rev-list --left-right --count origin/heads/origin/master...heads/origin/master
lerna ERR! fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/heads/origin/master...heads/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
lerna ERR! Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
lerna ERR! 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR! 
lerna ERR!     at makeError (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/child-process/node_modules/execa/index.js:169:9)
lerna ERR!     at Function.module.exports.sync (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/child-process/node_modules/execa/index.js:338:15)
lerna ERR!     at Object.execSync (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/child-process/index.js:21:16)
lerna ERR!     at Object.isBehindUpstream (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/git-utils/index.js:209:48)
lerna ERR!     at PublishCommand.initialize (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/publish/index.js:92:24)
lerna ERR!     at Promise.resolve.then (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/abide/node_modules/@lerna/command/index.js:228:24)
lerna ERR! lerna Command failed: git rev-list --left-right --count origin/heads/origin/master...heads/origin/master
lerna ERR! lerna fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/heads/origin/master...heads/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
lerna ERR! lerna Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
lerna ERR! lerna 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
lerna ERR! lerna 
lerna ERR! lerna 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 128
npm ERR! abide@1.0.0 publish: `lerna publish --yes --cd-version=patch`
npm ERR! Exit status 128
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the abide@1.0.0 publish script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T05_32_38_890Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 128
npm ERR! abide@1.0.0 jenkins: `npm run versions && npm run test && npm run publish`
npm ERR! Exit status 128
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the abide@1.0.0 jenkins script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-04-24T05_32_38_901Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to make an initial commit in your monorepo to make it work. You also need to have a clean working tree:

```
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "bootstrap lerna"
```

The error also happens in the repo if you type `git rev-parse HEAD`. After your first commit, you'll see that this no longer fails.