# "fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref" while using maven release plugin on VSTS

Tags: git, maven, azure-devops, maven-release-plugin

I get the following error output while running the maven release plugin prepare **under Microsoft Visual Studio Team Service (VSO)**

- Options: `--batch-mode -X -Dtag=$(releaseTag) -DreleaseVersion=$(releaseVersion) -DdevelopmentVersion=$(releaseNextSnapshotVersion)`
- Goal(s) : `clean release:clean release:prepare`
- on "repository" / git / "Clean" parameter is set to "true"

Doing the same in the command line or by using Jenkins (and checkout specific branch) works fine. Please notice that for me it's not a duplicate of 
["Git fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref" while using maven release plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351051/git-fatal-ref-head-is-not-a-symbolic-ref-while-using-maven-release-plugin) because I've not found any solution for VSO.

Full error stack is below. Any ideas how can this be solved?

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project myProject: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project myProject: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.checkin(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.performCheckins(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.ScmCommitPreparationPhase.runLogic(ScmCommitPreparationPhase.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.execute(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.executeCommand(AbstractGitScmProvider.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.checkin(AbstractGitScmProvider.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.AbstractScmProvider.checkIn(AbstractScmProvider.java:415)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractScmCommitPhase.checkin(AbstractScmCommitPhase.java:156)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.branch.GitBranchCommand.getCurrentBranch(GitBranchCommand.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.checkin.GitCheckInCommand.createPushCommandLine(GitCheckInCommand.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.checkin.GitCheckInCommand.executeCheckInCommand(GitCheckInCommand.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.checkin.AbstractCheckInCommand.executeCommand(AbstractCheckInCommand.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)
    ... 35 more
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from Maven: 1
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeMavenCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: Maven
******************************************************************************
System.Exception: Task Maven failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with your options and goals in VSTS Maven build. Is there any other settings you configured in the build definition? Can you share the entire build log?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Eddie-MSFT
I can't share the entire build log as it's not a public project.
I just setup 2 maven steps: prepare and perform plus git clean option. At queue time I select a dedicated git branch.
I'm using a not hosted agent: so for the next release I will retry with hosted agent to see if I reproduce the same issue. Keep you posted on