# Issue with pushing from my Jenkins release pipeline to Azure repo

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, azure-devops

I'm using maven release plugin to update versions in my pom files for releases. I have an issue that was related to  this post when jenkins is in detached head for checkout: ["Git fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref" while using maven release plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351051/git-fatal-ref-head-is-not-a-symbolic-ref-while-using-maven-release-plugin). I then went to additional behaviors and used the "checkout to specific local branch" and inputted the corresponding branch. Now I've run into an issue where its adding onto the URL as its trying to push back to the repo.

```
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: repository 'https://visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/Test/example/' not found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

How can I make it to where "example" is not added on to the URL for the push? Been stuck on this for a while, any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Edit: The "example" tag at the end of the URL is the artifact id in the child pom. This is tagged on due to our old svn url. How can I omit this from pushing to the new repo URL?

```
<groupId>com.example.something</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>trunk-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>${project.artifactId}</description>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added the artifact as "." this made the URL resolve... May not be conventional but worked.